# Jquery - Excluding elements based on whether a class exists or not in subsquent descendnets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I'm new to Jquery. Let's say I have a list and I want to exclude direct children of that list, the first li's, based on whether or not those direct li elements have a certain class within their decedents.

For instance I want to exclude the direct li element from the list "#mainList" that has a decedent with a class named "hello". I want to exclude the second list item.

I tried using the `has` function but that only selects the item I want to exclude. Then I tried using the not function. Thanks, I would appreciate any help.

```js
$('#mainList > li').has('.hello');
$('#mainList > li').not(function() {
  return $(this).has('.hello');
});
```

```html
<ul id="mainList">
  <li>mainItem1</li>
  <li>mainItem2
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5
        <ul>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
          <li>Item4</li>
          <li class="hello">Item5</li>
          <li>Item6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>mainItem2</li>
  <li>mainItem3</li>
  <li>mainItem4</li>
  <li>mainItem5</li>
  <li>mainItem6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what are you looking for exactly, its not very clear from your description of problem.

Comment: I want to exclude the direct list child from mainList that have decedents with a class named 'hello'. I wish to exclude mainItem2, since it has a decedent that has a class named 'hello'

Comment: Ok, got it, Can you change the code in the question, pls include mainItem2 just once as its confusing to see it twice. Will post my answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has some special CSS pseudo selectors that you can use. For this you could use :has in combination with the .not() method so:

```js
$('#mainList > li').not(':has(.hello').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<ul id="mainList">
  <li>Item0</li>
  <li>Item1
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5
        <ul>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
          <li>Item4</li>
          <li class="hello">Item5</li>
          <li>Item6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`jquery filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function - see a demo below:

```js
$('#mainList > li').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).find('li.hello').length;
}).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainList">
  <li>mainItem1</li>
  <li>mainItem2
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5
        <ul>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
          <li>Item4</li>
          <li class="hello">Item5</li>
          <li>Item6</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>mainItem2</li>
  <li>mainItem3</li>
  <li>mainItem4</li>
  <li>mainItem5</li>
  <li>mainItem6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It selects all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `children`:

```js
$('#mainList li').children(':not(.hello)').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainList">
  <li class="hello">Item0</li>
  <li>Item1
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5

        <ul>
          <li>Item1</li>
          <li>Item2</li>
          <li>Item3</li>
          <li>Item4</li>
          <li class="hello">Item5</li>
          <li>Item6</li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li>Item6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
</ul>
```